# time delay using 'after' method in tkinter works independently

Tags: python, tkinter

Consider this example

```
from tkinter import *
history_text_list=[]
window=Tk()
window.geometry("1366x768+1+1")
winner_lbl=Label(window, text="0", fg='red', font=("Comic Sans MS", 96))
winner_lbl.place(x=5, y=5)
a_pixel = PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
next_btn=Button(window, text="Next", font=("Comic Sans MS", 32), fg='blue', image=a_pixel, height = 70 , width = 130,compound="c")
next_btn.place(x=235, y=70)
history_text = StringVar()
history_label = Label(window, textvariable=history_text, wraplength=850, font=("Comic Sans MS", 16),justify="left",anchor="nw")
history_label.place(x=410, y=5)
def countdown(list_of_numbers):
    print('in function list-'+str(list_of_numbers))
    winner_lbl['fg'] = 'black'
    winner_lbl['text'] = list_of_numbers[0]
    list_of_numbers.pop(0)
    if list_of_numbers:
        window.after(500,countdown,list_of_numbers)
    else:
        winner_lbl['fg'] = 'red'
        return
def MyButtonClicked(self):
    one_to_hundred=list(range(1,10))
    countdown(one_to_hundred)
    history_text_list.append(10)
    history_text.set(str(history_text_list))
next_btn.bind('<Button-1>', MyButtonClicked)
window.mainloop()
```

Here, on pressing next button you will notice that label '0' increments to 9 but 10 gets added in history area quickly though it should happen after countdown function has ended .
What should I do to ensure serial execution ?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand. What is your expected output?

Comment: Do ***`print(len(range(1,100)))`*** and see what you get.

Comment: to  TheMaker and stovfl , I have updated code in my original post . Please run it then you will notice that 10 gets appended to text area quickly long before countdown ends. I have tried to provide minimum verifiable example to explain my question.

Comment: Please run my code then you can understand my point of view and remove negative vote to question.

Answer (score 1):

The `after` method returns right away. It does not wait for the timeout to expire. You should place the `history_text.set` call in your `countdown` function when the list of numbers is empty.

By the way, you can use `if list_of_numbers` instead of `if len(list_of_numbers)==0` to check if the list is empty.

Comment: It seems you are right . 'After' is non-blocking . Also your suggestion to check if list exists is helpful. I have updated code in my original post to make my question clear for others.
When I move 'history_text_list.append(10)' and 'history_text.set(str(history_text_list))' to else clause in countdown function then desired functionality is achieved . Thanks.